# Conditional mean or median in survival model

Tags: survival

what is the general framework to derive the conditional mean, E[T | T>s, x] or conditional median?  I don't know what my hazard function is yet.  But for my problem, I have tracked a group of people for some time.  Some have failed, but some have not.  I want to fit a model and predict the conditional failure time for ones who have not failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a semi-parametric method like Cox regression and the last time point is a censored observation rather than an event, you don't have information about survival beyond that last observation time. In that case you can't really calculate a conditional mean survival time as you don't know the limit to survival. It is possible to calculate a *restricted* mean survival up to a certain endpoint in time.

Survival software typically provides ways to estimate median survival (or any survival quantile) from a semi-parametric or parametric survival model, provided that the observed survival curve extends down to low enough survival values. For example, with R you could specify the covariate values of interest along with the model to the `survfit()` function and submit that output to a `quantile()` function. That will provide both point estimates and confidence intervals.

If you have a fully parametric model then you can use integral calculus to calculate a mean survival from the specific form of the model for a set of covariate values.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the use of integral calculus?

Comment: @sonicking once you have a fully parametric equation that describes the survival as a function of covariate values and time, you can calculate the mean or [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case) of the survival time conditional on any set of covariate values. Calculating expected/mean values for continuous distributions is an application of integral calculus. Statistical software will typically do that for you and provide confidence intervals based on the uncertainly in the coefficient estimates, but that's what's going on "under the hood."